# Approximate the mean of a function of two random variables

Tags: definite-integrals, random-variables

I have the next two random variables function:

$f(r,\theta) = \left(\frac{r^{2}}{D^2+2Dr\cos{\theta}+r^2}\right)^2$,

where $D$ is a constant and $r$ and $\theta$ have PDFs:

$f_{r}=\frac{2r}{R^2 - R_{0}^2}, R_{0}\leq r \leq R$

and

$f_{\theta}=\frac{1}{2\pi}$, $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$, respectively.

The mean of the function can be calculated employing:

$\overline{f(r,\theta)}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{R_{0}}^{R}f(r,\theta)f_{r}f_{\theta}drd\theta$.

Unfortunately, I did not get a closed form expression for that integral. In addition, I used the approach to the mean based on Taylor series, but because the variance of $r$ is too large for my problem, this approximation is too far from its real value.

Any ideas to solve this integral or to approximate the mean of the function?

Thank you in advance by your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integral can be solved in closed form (at least for $R>R_0>D$) using the identity
$$
(a+b)^{-s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty dx\ x^{s-1}e^{-x (a+b)}\ ,
$$
for $a+b>0$. Write
$$
\overline{f(r,\theta)}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{R_{0}}^{R}\left(\frac{r^{2}}{D^2+2Dr\cos{\theta}+r^2}\right)^2 \frac{2r}{R^2 - R_{0}^2} \frac{1}{2\pi}drd\theta
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(2)}\frac{2}{R^2-R_0^2}\int_0^\infty dx\ x\ e^{-x D^2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}\int_{R_{0}}^{R}dr\ r^5 e^{-2D r x\cos\theta-x r^2}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(2)}\frac{2}{R^2-R_0^2}\int_{R_{0}}^{R}dr\ r^5\int_0^\infty dx\ x\ e^{-x D^2} e^{-x r^2}I_0\left(2Drx\right)
$$
$$
= \frac{2}{R^2-R_0^2}\int_{R_{0}}^{R}dr\frac{r^5 \left(D^2+r^2\right)}{| D^2-r^2| ^3}=\frac{2}{R^2-R_0^2}\int_{R_{0}}^{R}dr\frac{r^5 \left(D^2+r^2\right)}{(r^2-D^2) ^3}\ ,
$$
assuming $R>R_0>D$. Here, $I_0(x)$ is a Bessel function.

Changing variables $r=Dy$, we get
$$
\frac{2 D^2}{R^2-R_0^2}\int_{R_{0}/D}^{R/D}dy\frac{y^5 \left(1+y^2\right)}{(y^2-1) ^3}\ .
$$
The primitive of the integrand is (ignoring an additive constant)
$$
\Phi(y)=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{5}{2 \left(y^2-1\right)}-\frac{1}{2 \left(y^2-1\right)^2}+2 \log \left(y^2-1\right)\ .
$$
Therefore, the final result is
$$
\boxed{\overline{f(r,\theta)}=\frac{2}{(R/D)^2-(R_0/D)^2}\left[\Phi(R/D)-\Phi(R_0/D)\right]}
$$

I checked with Mathematica for a few values of $R>R_0>D$ and it seems to work.

**EDIT** In the case $D>R>R_0$, the only change is in the absolute value $|D^2-r^2|^3$ in the denominator a few lines up, which changes sign. So the net effect is a minus sign overall, and in this case the average reads
$$
\boxed{\overline{f(r,\theta)}=\frac{2}{(R/D)^2-(R_0/D)^2}\left[-\Phi(R/D)+\Phi(R_0/D)\right]}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much Pierpaolo. Your answer is very helpful. I have some cases for which D> R> Ro. Some ideas for this scenario? Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @Henry I have edited the answer to include also the case $D>R>R_0$ (it is a trivial change).

Comment: On a side note, please bear in mind that when people take time to answer your questions, and the answers are helpful to you, it is good to upvote those that are helpful. That's one way to say "thank you" so to speak in a more 'tangible' way. Also, for any question you ask, you can "accept" an answer. To upvote, click on the greyed-out up-arrow to the left of the answer. To accept an answer, click on the "greyed-out" check-mark next to the answer you want to accept. That indicates that the answer was particularly helpful/ and/or that it has fully answered your question.

Comment: Again thank you very much @PierpaoloVivo. Your help was invaluable and thank you very much for the prompt replies. In addition, note that for D>R>Ro, to avoid calculating the logarithm of negative numbers, the term Log [y ^ 2-1] can be rewritten as Log [1-y ^ 2] and the answer is the same.

Comment: You're most welcome. PP